# How to redirect Multisite sites to the main site

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, cookies

I have a multisite installation that I have network enabled a plugin that sets every site to display a basic "Coming Soon" page.

However, what I would really like to do is redirect from all the sites to the main site, and create a cookie that stores the site before it was redirected.

For example, if a user goes to:
http://somedomain.com/testsite1
Then, what I would like to do is to create a cookie that has value:
site=testsite1
and then redirect to:
http://somedomain.com
where the "Coming Soon" page will be displayed.

Any help is welcomed!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you would want to set the cookie after the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fix.  It doesn't quite solve everything I need, but it's a great start.

```html
add_action('wp_loaded', 'redirect_to_main_site');
function redirect_to_main_site()
{
   if (is_main_site()) {
       return '';
   }

   setcookie('site', get_current_blog_id());
   wp_redirect(network_site_url());
   exit;
}
~
```